# IntelliJ Maven project import

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, ide

Once i import the existing maven project into my IntelliJ IDE. Why the project name is coming as "main" only.

[image]

I am just simpling opening the existing maven project into IntelliJ.
Please help what can be done to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `main` is the root your project. The root of project is the directory where the `pom.xml` is. You should consider [**Standard Directory Layout**](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your `pom.xml` file should be in a root directory, not in the `main` directory.

For now you have your `pom.xml` in the `main` directory so IntellijIDEA recognizes the `main` as a maven module. 
Please move your `pom.xml` on the same level as `src` directory.